# Fire up two links with one click

Tags: javascript, html

Good day.
I've checked lots of questions regarding this but can't find one related to what I want to do. I want to fire up two links with one click. The first link opens on the current tab and the second link on a new tab. I've seen this suggestion from another question:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a>
```

But this will definitely not work because the second link gets blocked by the browser and only the first link will successfully open. If you know a way, please share.
Thanks.

Comment: if you are referring to chrome\s default popup blocker, blocking the 2nd link - it's meant to do exactly that. block popups. you can not bypass it. not using `setInterval()` not using javascript +a:link, or any other hacky method. its by design.

Comment: yes, you're right. all browsers are like that. they tend to block the second tab if two or more new tabs are opened at once. but not if only one new tab is opened. that's why I only want one new tab opened. first URL on the current tab then second URL on the new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get your job done-
As you said(The first link opens on the current tab and the second link on a new tab)..this does that:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a>
```

Comment: wow thanks. you saved me. that worked. I've been using that method to open a link on a new tab but didn't tried it on this one to open two URLs. the "http://google.com" part, I use something like "javascript:(void)" to hide the URL.

Comment: glad to be of help..:-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will open up both websites in a new tab. Make sure you run this code within your own code sample, as it will not do anything when running the code snippet on stack-overflows code sandbox.

```js
document.getElementById('button-link').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');
  window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', '_blank');
});
```

```html
Solution 1:

<button id="button-link">Link</button>

Solution 2:

<button onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', '_blank');">Link</button>
```

Comment: nope, I'm sorry. I already tried that and the second new tab is blocked. it will open two new tabs but only the first new tab gets successfully opened. the second new tab obviously gets blocked. I only want one new tab for the two URLs. first URL on the current tab then second URL on the new tab.

Comment: @Nimmimonie Browser details? do you have a blocker? See the revised code, one link will open in the current tab and the other one will open in a new tab.